# Values missing when loaded from Pandas HDF5 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I've some twitter feed loaded in Pandas Series that I want to store in HDF5 format. Here's a sample of it:

```
    >>> feeds[80:90]

    80    BØR MAN STARTE en tweet med store bokstaver? F...
    81    @NRKSigrid @audunlysbakken Har du husket Per S...
    82    Lurer på om IS har fått med seg kaoset ved Eur...
    83    synes han hørte på P3 at Opoku uttales Opoko. ...
    84    De statsbærende partiene Ap og Høyre må ta sky...
    85    April 2014. Blir MDG det nye arbeider @partiet...
    86                       MDG: Hasj for kjøtt. #valg2015
    87               Grønt skifte.. https://t.co/OuM8quaMz0
    88                    Kinderegg https://t.co/AsECmw2sV9
    89    MDG for honning, frukt og grønt. https://t.co/...
    Name: feeds, dtype: object
```

Whenever I try to load the above data from a saved HDF5 file, some values are missing and are replaced by `''`... And the same values reappear when I change the indexing. For example, while storing rows with index `84-85`:

```
    >>> store = pd.HDFStore('feed.hd5')
    >>> store.append('feed', feeds[84:86], min_itemsize=200, encoding='utf-8')
    >>> store.close()
```

when I read the file, the value of `84th` row is now missing:

```
    >>> pd.read_hdf('feed.hd5', 'feed')

    84                                                     
    85    April 2014. Blir MDG det nye arbeider @partiet...
    Name: feeds, dtype: object
```

I get the same output as above if I do this way too:

```
    >>> feeds[84:86].to_hdf('feed.hd5', 'feed', format='table', data_columns=True)
    >>> pd.read_hdf('feed.hd5', 'feed')
```

But If I change the index to, say, `[84:87]` from `[84:86]`, the `84th` row is now loaded.

```
    >>> feeds[84:87].to_hdf('feed.hd5', 'feed', format='table', data_columns=True)
    >>> res = pd.read_hdf('feed.hd5', 'feed')
    >>> res

    84    De statsbærende partiene Ap og Høyre må ta sky...
    85    April 2014. Blir MDG det nye arbeider @partiet...
    86                       MDG: Hasj for kjøtt. #valg2015
    Name: feeds, dtype: object
```

But now, the loaded string is missing some characters when compared with the original tweet. here's that `84th` row valued tweet:

```
    >>> # Original tweet (Length: 140)
    >>> print (feeds[84])

    De statsbærende partiene Ap og Høyre må ta skylda for Miljøpartiets fremgang. Velgerne har sett at SV og V ikke vinner frem i miljøspørsmål.

    >>> # Loaded tweet (Length: 134)
    >>> print (res[84])

    De statsbærende partiene Ap og Høyre må ta skylda for Miljøpartiets fremgang. Velgerne har sett at SV og V ikke vinner frem i miljøspø
```

I plan to use Python 3.3.x mainly for this unicode column support in PyTables (Am I wrong?) but could not store all the data successfully, yet. Can anyone explain this and let me know how can I avoid it ?

I am using `OS: Mac OS X Yosemite, Pandas: 0.16.2, Python: 3.3.5, PyTables: 3.2.0`

UPDATE: I confirmed with HDFView (http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) that the data is indeed getting stored always (although with some last characters missing) but I am unable to load it successfully every time though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the doc-string [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.append.html?highlight=hdfstore.append#pandas.HDFStore.append).

You need to provide `encoding='utf-8'` otherwise this will be stored with your default python encoding (which might or might not work). Reading will use the written encoding.

The data

```
In [13]: df[84:86]
Out[13]: 
              tweet_id  username                 tweet_time                                              tweet
84  641437756275720192  @nicecap  2015-09-09T02:27:33+00:00  De statsbÃ¦rende partiene Ap og HÃ¸yre mÃ¥ ta sky...
85  641434661391101952  @nicecap  2015-09-09T02:15:15+00:00  April 2014. Blir MDG det nye arbeider @partiet...
```

Appending, supply the encoding.

```
In [11]: store.append('feed',df[84:86],encoding='utf-8')
```

Supply the encoding when *read* as well

```
In [12]: store.select('feed',encoding='utf-8')
Out[12]: 
              tweet_id  username                 tweet_time                                              tweet
84  641437756275720192  @nicecap  2015-09-09T02:27:33+00:00  De statsbÃ¦rende partiene Ap og HÃ¸yre mÃ¥ ta sky...
85  641434661391101952  @nicecap  2015-09-09T02:15:15+00:00  April 2014. Blir MDG det nye arbeider @partiet...
```

Here's how its stored

```
In [14]: store.get_storer('feed')
Out[14]: frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->2,ncols->4,indexers->[index])

In [15]: store.get_storer('feed').attrs
Out[15]: 
/feed._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 15 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := [],
    encoding := 'utf-8',
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {1: {'names': [None], 'type': 'Index'}, 'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    metadata := [],
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['tweet_id', 'username', 'tweet_time', 'tweet'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.15.2',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['values_block_0', 'values_block_1']]
```

So, I suppose this is a bug in that I should by default use the stored encoding when reading. I created an issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11126)

Comment: Thanks jeff for mentioning it. I have edited it in the post. But it still didn't help. I tried reading it via the context manager `(with HDFStore(...))` and `read_hdf`. The values are still missing. Is there anything else I am missing ?

Comment: But strangely if I change the index as mentioned above, it's loading alright (but with fewer characters). So when I load the complete file, many rows have `' '` but while retrieving for only few indices, they are loading fine. I could not understand this. :-/

Comment: can you post a sample file (and show how you are reading with ``read_csv``), just to get the exact same data

Comment: Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kp9rzhcqsk373gw/feed_dump.csv?dl=0.

I am reading the CSV as `data = pd.read_csv('feed_dump.csv', header=0, index=None, encoding='utf-8', engine='python')` and taking only the tweets as `feeds = data['tweet']`.

Comment: Hey @jeff, I have tried your solution _with the encoding_ but still couldn't load the `84th` row... May I  know if there's something else wrong ? I have attached a screenshot of it here along with the `pd.show_versions( )` : https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh5kj0p6kpz3vto/Error_Pandas_HDF5.png?dl=0 . Can you please take a look ?

Comment: Also, can you tell if it's possible to enforce encodings with `pd.to_hdf`and `pd.read_hdf` (anytime in future, may be) ? It doesn't seem to have any effect for now, (for my case at least)

Comment: And btw, please replace `index=None` with `index_col=None` in the code above (in the comments) to correctly read the CSV file. I couldn't edit that comment.

Comment: make sure that you are rewriting the file (e.g. ``mode='w'`` as you may actually have an old one. set PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8' in your shell. otherwise it should work (my tests is on the same versions as yours)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and could partly able to correct it . If someone first tweets a tweet that is near to 140 characters and another person retweets it, the latter one doesn't contain the full tweet as there will be some text pre-appended for retweets like `RT @username:`. As a result, the tweet is now more than 140 characters and hence is stripped down to 140 and is obtained as such via twitter APIs for python like `tweepy` or `Python twitter tools` (these are the two I have tested...). Sometimes the last character of these kind of tweets is a character `'…'` which has a length of `1` and an ordinal value of `8230` (try `chr(8230)` in *python 3.x* or `unichr(8230)` for *python 2.x*...). When these are stored in a HDF5 file and read via `pd.read_hdf`, it could not be done and instead pandas replaces the whole tweet with just `''`.

This could be rectified as below:

```
>>> # replace that '…' character with '' (empty char)
>>> ch = chr(8230)
>>> feeds.str.replace(ch, '')

>>> # Store it in HDF5 now... # Not sure if it preserves the encoding...
>>> feeds.to_hdf('feed.h5', 'feed', format='table', append=True, encoding='utf-8', data_columns=True)

>>> # If you prefer this way
>>> with pd.HDFStore('feed.h5') as store:
        store.append('feed', feeds, min_itemsize=200, encoding='utf-8')

>>> # Now read it safely
>>> pd.read_hdf('feed.h5', 'feed')
```

However, the problem still appears sometimes if there are some unicode characters... Giving the `encoding='utf-8'` option didn't really help, at least for my case. Any help in this regard is appreciated... :)